# How to have matrices side by side in latex?

Tags: matrices

I'm new to latex and all of my matrices seem to be created on new lines, I can't seem to put them side by side.  Here is what I am doing to make a matrix (with the 2d identity matrix as an example):

```
\[ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right) \]
```

Am I making it wrong?  How can I place a second matrix directly beside this, as you would when doing matrix mathematics?  Thanks

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Don't enclose each array with `\[ ... \]`; instead, put all the arrays that you want together within one set of delimeters.  Like this:

```
\[ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right)
%
\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right)
\]
```

You should read the `mathmode` documentation.  It should be part of your TeX Distribution, and has lots of examples to follow.

Comment: This makes sense.  However, does this still handle things like [Matrix][vector] = [vector] all one one line?

Comment: @bbel Sure. As long as they will fit on the same line, you can just put them one after another like this (no blank lines in between which is why I separated the two matrices in my example with a `%` (comment character)).

Answer (score 13):

This is slightly tangential, but you might find it convenient to use the `pmatrix` environment (defined in `amsmath.sty`)

```
\[
\begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0 \\ 0 & e^{i\pi/k}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
  u \\ v
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
  u \\ -v
\end{pmatrix}
\]
```

Answer (score 10):

The idea is to enclose both matrices in one block i.e. `\[  \]` see this example

```
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
    a  &  b      \\
    c  &  d      
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
    8  &  1      \\
    7  &  6      
\end{bmatrix} 
\]
```

It will be something like:

[image]

Comment: This is already covered by the other answer(s).

Answer (score 5):

like this

```
\[ \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right) \times \left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right) =\left( \begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{array} \right)\]
```

You need to place the matrices inside the math environment

Comment: Inside the math environment by surrounding them with the dollar sign operator? Because that gives me errors in itself..

Comment: \\[..\\] is a math environment When you use this environment the math expression is written on a single line. Like Alan, I think you  should read the mathmode.pdf documentation from Herbert Voss.

Answer (score 1):

I was confused by the answers and the syntax so I'll share mine and include an image. I'm using `\begin{equation}` which is arguably less convenient but also more verbose for beginners (like myself) than using the `\[` syntax.
To be clear, what is causing the matrices to be on separate lines is the blank line between the min the code. If you fill it with the placeholder `%` or remove the line completely it will render like the attached picture. (Thanks to Teepeemm for clarifying what `%` is!)

```
\begin{equation}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    C_1 & C_2 & C_3 & C_4 
  \end{bmatrix}
  %
  \begin{bmatrix}
    z_1 \\
    z_2 \\
    z_3 \\
    z_4 \\
  \end{bmatrix} 
\end{equation}
```

[image: two matrices/arrays on the same line]

Comment: The `%` in the middle is a place holder that doesn't need to be there.  TeX doesn't allow have a blank line, so the `%` gives a line that isn't blank but doesn't have any consequences.  Also, the `\[` syntax is equivalent to `\begin{equation*}`.  `\begin{equation}` (without the `*`) will number the equation.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification on the `%`. That explains why my matrices didn't line up side-by-side when adding a space between them. They do however line up correctly without the `%` and without an empty line between them. Thanks for clearing that up for me! :) I'll modify my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just doing this is enough; you don't need `\left` and `\right`.

```
\[
\begin{bmatrix}
z_{1}^{(1)} \\ 
z_{2}^{(1)} \\
\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix}
a_{0}^{(0)} & a_{1}^{(0)} & a_{2}^{(0)} \\
a_{0}^{(0)} & a_{1}^{(0)} & a_{2}^{(0)}
\end{bmatrix}
%
\begin{bmatrix}
w_{10}^{(1)} & w_{20}^{(1)} \\
w_{11}^{(1)} & w_{21}^{(1)} \\
w_{12}^{(1)} & w_{22}^{(1)} 
\end{bmatrix}
\]
```

Comment: Please have a look at [Why is \[ … \] preferable to $$ … $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/82917). Furthermore you should at least mention that this code requires the `amsmath` package.