# Aligning bmatrix-matrices next to each other?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, matrices

I have this code:

```
\[
    \begin{bmatrix}
    Pagerank&Sidnummer\\
    0.068945&2\\
    0.068945&3\\
    0.076517&1\\
    0.076517&4\\
    0.11536&7\\
    0.11536&8\\
    0.11536&6\\
    0.11536&5\\
    0.14069&9\\
    0.14069&12\\
    0.16501&14\\
    0.33015&13\\
    0.33015&15\\
    0.56601&10\\
    0.56601&11\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\]
\[
    \begin{bmatrix}
    Pagerank&Sidnummer\\
    0.076517&1\\
    0.068945&2\\
    0.068945&3\\
    0.076517&4\\
    0.11536&5\\
    0.11536&6\\
    0.11536&7\\
    0.11536&8\\
    0.14069&9\\
    0.56601&10\\
    0.56601&11\\
    0.14069&12\\
    0.33015&13\\
    0.16501&14\\
    0.33015&15\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\]
```

And individually the matrices are correct. But I don't like the way they display on the screen. The second matrix is placed beneath the first one. I want them to share the horizontal space and lay next to each other. Is this possible?

Comment: and btw I read http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9901/how-to-have-matrices-side-by-side-in-latex but if I remove the \] \[ that are in between the two matrices, it results in many errors.

Comment: You can remove `]` and `[` but without leaving any blank lines; in my answer I used % to comment out one blank line between the matrices thus making the code more "readable" while preventing an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place them inside the same displayed environment:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \textrm{Pagerank} & \textrm{Sidnummer}\\
    0.068945&2\\
    0.068945&3\\
    0.076517&1\\
    0.076517&4\\
    0.11536&7\\
    0.11536&8\\
    0.11536&6\\
    0.11536&5\\
    0.14069&9\\
    0.14069&12\\
    0.16501&14\\
    0.33015&13\\
    0.33015&15\\
    0.56601&10\\
    0.56601&11\\
    \end{bmatrix}%\hspace*{20pt} % to increase the horizontal space
%
    \begin{bmatrix}
    \textrm{Pagerank} & \textrm{Sidnummer}\\
    0.076517&1\\
    0.068945&2\\
    0.068945&3\\
    0.076517&4\\
    0.11536&5\\
    0.11536&6\\
    0.11536&7\\
    0.11536&8\\
    0.14069&9\\
    0.56601&10\\
    0.56601&11\\
    0.14069&12\\
    0.33015&13\\
    0.16501&14\\
    0.33015&15\\
    \end{bmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

Note that I used the `\textrm` command to change the font for the text part. You can use `\hspace` to increase the horizontal separation between the matrices (commented out in my example).

Comment: Thank you, that worked. The % in between the two matrices seem to be key, if I remove it I get an error. Why is that? I'm marking this as the correct solution, it works perfect.

Comment: @Calle: `\par` is not allowed in math mode; leaving a blank line is equivalent to using `\par` and this will trigger an error (tipically the well known `Missing $ inserted`).