# Centering Two Matrices and Putting Them Side By Side

Tags: matrices

Here is the portion of my code that is rather bothersome:

```
\begin{center}

    \begin{matrix}
      E_1  \\
      E_2 
    \end{matrix}

    \begin{bmatrix} 
      1 & h & 2 \\
     -5 & 15 & -12 
    \end{bmatrix}

\end{center}
```

And the result is

[image]

How do I go about getting the E_1 E_2 column to the left of the bmatrix?

Comment: If you're interested in providing row-labels for the matrix, consider reviewing [Where is the `\matrix` command?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/26434/5764)

Comment: You must have got errors from that, matrix is a math command, replace center by `\[` `\]` and delete the blank line

Comment: Alternatively, the following duplicate source should help: [How to have matrices side by side in latex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9901/5764)